# Namespace, form_for and named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, form-for, named-routing

I have two controllers grouped under the `admin` namespace, like the following:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :projects
  get "profile", to: "users#edit"
  post "profile", to: "users#create"
end
```

In a `form_for` for a `resource`, it works fine [as eplained in the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification):

```
form_for [:admin, @project]
```

But when it comes to a named route, like the above `admin/profile`, I have no clue what to put as an argument in the `form_for`. If I simply use `form_for(@user)`, the `edit` action works fine and the form is displayed correctly, but when submitting I get the following error:

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/2"
```

When I try `form_for [:admin, @user]`, the form is not displayed complaing about:

```
undefined method `admin_user_path'
```

**How should the `form_for be constructed in a named route under a namespace?`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
form_for(@user, url: admin_profile_path) do |f|
```

Run `rake routes` to list all routes.

Comment: Excellent! (And I had to change my wrong routing of the update action as well: `patch "profil", to: "users#update"`)